# Asymptotic for number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ squares, uniform in $n,k \to +\infty$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics, partitions

Let $p^{(s)}(n)$ be the number of ways of writing the positive integer $n$ as a sum of perfect $s$-powers, where the order does not matter. For example, $p^{(2)}(9) = 4$ since
$$9 = 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2$$
$$9 = 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 +  2^2\phantom{1^2 +\;\,+ 1^2 + 1^2}$$
$$9 = 1^2 + 2^2 + 2^2\phantom{ + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 2^2\;\,+ 1^2 + 1^2}$$
$$9 = 3^2 \phantom{+ 2^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 2^2\;\,+ 1^2 + 1^2}$$
and there are no other ways of writing $9$ as sum of squares.

It is known that 
$$\log p^{(s)}(n) \sim (s+1)\left(\frac1{2}\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac1{s}\right)\zeta\!\left(1+\frac1{s}\right)\right)^{s/(s+1)} n^{1/(s+1)},$$
as $n \to +\infty$ (See *Hardy and Littlewood, Asymptotic formulæ in combinatory analysis, Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society, 2, XVII, 1918, 75-115*).

My question is: If $p_k^{(s)}(n)$ is the number of ways of writing the positive integer $n$ as a sum of *exactly $k$* perfect $s$-powers, is there an asymptotic formula for $\log p_k^{(s)}(n)$ holding in a reasonable range of $n,k \to \infty$? I am particularly interested in the case of squares $s = 2$.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Do you already know the asymptotics for fixed $k$ as $n\to\infty$, connected with "Waring's problem"?

Comment: So $9 = 3^2$ doesn't count, or should $p^{(2)}(9) = 4$?  In the latter case the sequence is [A001156](https://oeis.org/A001156).  There are also sequences for sums of two nonzero squares [A025426](https://oeis.org/A025426), three nonzero squares [A025427](https://oeis.org/A025427), etc., which are each columns of the triangle [A243148](https://oeis.org/A243148), although these do not mention asymptotic formulas.

Comment: @BrianHopkins Sorry, I forgot $9 = 3^2$, thanks!

Comment: @GregMartin No, I don't. However, I am more interested in an asymptotic holding for $k \to +\infty$ (in some range of $n$ depending on $k$, or vice versa)

Comment: It's going to be quite important to the answer to know the relative sizes of $n$ and $k$ ... what do you have in mind?

Comment: @GregMartin Essentially, if I have a non-trivial asymptotic with $k \to +\infty$ I am fine.

Answer (score 1):

The folowing is a known result on Waring's problem: For fixed $k$ (sufficiently large), the number of ways to write $n$ as an *ordered* sum of $k$ squares is asymptotic to
$$
\frac{\Gamma(3/2)^k}{\Gamma(k/2)} {\frak S}_2(n)n^{k/2-1},
$$
where ${\frak S}_2(n)$ (the "singular series") is a complicated but bounded function of $n$. Almost all of these representations use distinct squares, and so the number of *unordered* representations is asymptotic to this expression divided by $k!$.

For each such $k$, this asymptotic formula holds when $n$ is sufficiently large in terms of $k$. Therefore if we let $n$ go to infinity sufficiently quickly in terms of $k$, this asymptotic formula holds uniformly in $k$ and $n$. (Note that ${\frak S}_2(n)$ is not a smooth function—it depends on the factorization properties of $n$.)

Comment: "this asymptotic formula holds when $n$ is sufficiently large in terms of $k$" <- Then, I think the point is finding if somebody has worked out an explicit version of this statement, like "for $n \ge f(k)$", where $f$ is an explicit function.

Comment: I totally agree that this is the right starting point for you!